# How to embed a variable prefix in a NSUserDefault reference?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I have a bit of code that looks like this:

```
[defaults setObject:@"sample_3-2.aiff" forKey:@"mySample"];
```

But I really want to change the "sample" word in my value to a variable, which I guess would look something like this:

```
[defaults setObject:@"%@_3-2.aiff" , myString forKey:@"mySample"];
```

Which of course doesn't work (and therefore I need your help). My goal is to actually make it work by calling the prefix from another NSUserDefault, something I image is like this:

```
[defaults setObject:@"%@_3-2.aiff" [defaults stringForKey:@"myPrefix"] forKey:@"mySample"];
```

Can someone please let me know how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap the whole object in a NSString:

```
[defaults setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_3-2.aiff", [defaults stringForKey:@"myPrefix"]] forKey:@"mySample"];
```